# How to print "\\0" in C language

Tags: c, printf

I wanted to print `\0` using `printf`. First I found `printf("ab\0c")` is not right because I can only get "`ab`". Then I found a way to print "`ab\0c`" using `printf("ab\\0c")`.  But that brings a new problem. What if I want to print `"ab\\0c"`? I want to print it in only one sentence. Do you have any good way to do this?

Comment: What is your new problem with `printf("ab\\0c");`? It prints `ab\0c` without a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Printing** a single backslash (as opposed to using it as an escape sequence) needs a double backslash to undo the escaping., so basically

- If you want to print `ab\0c` you need `printf("ab\\0c")` (2 times 1 is 2)
- If you want to print `ab\\0c` you need `printf("ab\\\\0c")` (2 times 2 is 4)
- ...

Answer (score 3):

`\` "escapes" special characters (allows you to write `\n` and `\"` etc). If you want to print a `\` you need to escape that (since `\` is a special character itself). Put `\\` in your string to print `\`.

If you want to print `\\` your format string has to be `\\\\` (i.e. escape both `\`s).

Answer (score 1):

One `\\` prints one `\`, to print `\\`, use:

```
printf("ab\\\\0c");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this program:

```
printf("ab\\\\0c");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a double '\' to escape:

```
printf("ab\\\0c");
```